# how to queue to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple functions in my code but I wanted to run my function first to which I want.....

By the way of my coding func1() is running after all the functions func2, func3, func4.

```
func1();//run it first forcefully with js
func2();//this should run at same time of func1
func3();//this should run after the func1, and func2
func4();//this should run after the func1, and func2
```

What I was trying it with jquery like queue() method `func1().queue();` but seems wrong as we cannot queue the function from the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/)

So, is there any technique?

Comment: Promises maybe? I'm on a phone so I can't try it but it's worth a shot: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise there are libraries for this, and maybe jquery has it. // edit: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single threaded. Only one function can access a page. You could do something with [web-workers](http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/introducing-html5-web-workers/). But those can't access the DOM. They also require a modern HTML5 browser.

For running functions one after the other its probably easiest to just call function 3 at the end of function 2.

Answer (score 0):

Boelensman1 is right. And Jorg adviced Promisses.

But assuming that all your functions are asynchronous, and promises are not available...
func1 and func2 should run callback when it finished.

```
function mockQueue(fn1, fn2, readyCallback) {
  // It's running immediately
  fn1(decFnCount); // run it first forcefully with js
  fn2(decFnCount); // this should run at same time of func1

  var fnCount = 2;
  function decFnCount() {
    if (!fnCount--) readyCallback();
  }
}

mockQueue(func1, func2, function() {
  // It's waiting func1 and func2
  func3(); //this should run after the func1, and func2
  func4(); //this should run after the func1, and func2
})
```